# The orthogonal operator onto $ran(T)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have read that the least square solution for the operator in Hilbert space is given by $$T^*Tx=T^*y$$
where $T$ is the operator $T: X\rightarrow Y$, and $T^*$ is the adjoint operator. Obviously, this conclusion comes from defining the orthogonal projection onto the space of $ran(T)$, but I have no idea how to define such operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any closed subspace $M$ of a Hilbert space $H$, the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$ is the unique $m\in M$ such that $(x-m)\perp M$. This is the kind of projection that you have no doubt seen in Calculus. Just as in Calculus, the orthogonal projection $m$ of $x$ onto $M$ is also the closest point projection of $x$ onto $M$, i.e.,
$$
                         \|x-m\| \le \|x-m'\|,\;\;\; m'\in M,
$$
with equality iff $m=m'$. The converse is also true: the closest point projection of $x$ onto the closed subspace $M$ is also the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$. It is particularly easy to show that orthogonal projection is unique; so closest point projection is unique as well.

When formulated as the closest point projection, it is possible to choose a sequence $\{ m_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\|x-m_{n}\| \le \inf_{m\in M}\|x-m'\|+1/n$, and to show that $\{ m_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence and, hence, converges to some $m\in M$. The limit is the orthogonal projection. So, basically, if you can find a sequence of points $\{ m_{n} \}$ in $M$ whose sequence  $\{ \|x-m_{n}\|\}$ of distances converges to the minimum distance $d=\inf_{m\in M}\|x-m\|$, then the sequence of vectors must converge to the closest-point/orthogonal projection! Of course, you have to know the minimum distance to know that your sequence is converging. :)

Given $y \in H$, the least squares problem involves finding a vector $x$ which minimizes
$$
                         \|Tx-y\|.
$$
You'll recognize this problem as one of finding the closest point projection of $y$ onto the range of $T$. However, because $T$ may not have a closed range, it is not always possible to find a projection in a Hilbert space. If the range of $T$ is closed, then any closest point projection of $y$ onto the range has the form $Tx_{0}$ for some $x_{0}\in H$, and the orthogonality condition equivalent to closest point projection requires
$$
               (y-Tx_{0})\perp Tx,\;\;\; x \in H.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
   0 = (y-Tx_{0},Tx) = (T^{\star}y-T^{\star}Tx_{0},x),\;\;\; x \in H, \\
           \iff T^{\star}y=T^{\star}Tx_{0}.
$$
Assuming the range of $T$ is closed, then there exists such $x_{0}$ and $Tx_{0}$ is unique because orthogonal projection of $y$ onto the range of $T$ is unique. That means that any other such $x_{0}'$ satisfies $T(x_{0}-x_{0}')=0$ or $x_{0}'=x_{0}+n$ where $n \in\mathcal{N}(T)$.